# summed daylie sales of last 30 days output in google chart

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a table with sales. From this table i take all results of the last 30 days, sum the prices with the same date and get this as array.

SQL:

```
SELECT date
     , price
     , id
     , SUM(price) AS daylieprice 
  FROM sales 
 WHERE id = :id 
   AND date BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() , '%Y-%m-%d') - interval 1 month AND DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() , '%Y-%m-%d')) 
 GROUP 
    BY date
```

So i have for example:
ARRAY  ['date']        -  ARRAY ['daylieprice']
"2017-03-29"  -  "1" 
"2017-04-02"  -  "5" 
 
"2017-04-04"  -  "3"

Google chart is looking like that:

```
['<? echo date('d', strtotime("-2 day")) ?>', VALUE]
['<? echo date('d', strtotime("-1 day")) ?>', VALUE]
['<? echo date('d') ?> ', VALUE]
```

Is there a way to output the value of the array like that:

```
date('d', strtotime("-2 day") , ARRAY ['daylieprice']);
date('d', strtotime("-1 day") , ARRAY ['daylieprice']);
date('d', ARRAY ['daylieprice']);
```

Should mean to take the array value easy with date('d') or date('d', strtotime("-1 day") witouth making a loop for each value ?

Or does i have to make for every day a sql request?

Comment: Store dates using a date data type. Then see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry (don't know if i understand well) the query is working fine. Now i just need to output the values of the Array according to my last questions above.

Comment: Well, if you think the problem has nothing to do with (my)sql, I'd suggest removing both the sql and the tag from the question.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this. I use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to give more control and felxibility with input and output formats. This loops through your input array and subtracts 2 days from first entry, 1 day from 2nd entry and keeps 3rd entry the same:

```
<?php
$input = [
  [
    'date' => '2017-03-29',
    'daylieprice' => 1,
  ],
  [
    'date' => '2017-04-02',
    'daylieprice' => 5,
  ],
  [
    'date' => '2017-04-04',
    'daylieprice' => 3,
  ],
];

$output = [];
$number_of_dates = count($input) - 1;
foreach ($input as $v) {
  $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $v['date'])
    ->modify(sprintf('-%d days', $number_of_dates))
    ->format('Y-m-d');

  $number_of_dates--;    
  $output[] = "'" . $date . "', " . $v['daylieprice'];
}
```

This produces an array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => '2017-03-27', 1
    [1] => '2017-04-01', 5
    [2] => '2017-04-04', 3
)
```

Hope this helps and you can figure out exactly how to implement it to solve your problem.

Edit: just saw `echo date('d'` so maybe you only want the day of the month, that's easy, you can just change `->format('Y-m-d');` in the loop to `->format('d');`

Demo: https://eval.in/784353

Comment: Thanks for your work, looks impressive, but it's not i exactly what i need. i searched more a function where i can call the date for example ('d') or ('d-1') and i get the value of the array with exactly that date. I hoped it would be easier.